# get coordinate and frame from UIImage in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3

How to get frame of shape from `UIImage` for that i used image like 
[image]

anyone please help me to achieve that.

Comment: you need in objective C or swift

Comment: i need swift code @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Please tale a look at this link : https://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/real-time-object-detection-using-mser-in-ios

Answer (score 2):

you can get this info from the imageView frame that has the image inside of it or the image its self. Since you haven't said wether you use an imageView or not here is both:

**getting size and coordinates from imageView:**

```
let x:CGFloat = imageView.frame.origin.x
let y:CGFloat = imageView.frame.origin.y

let width:CGFloat = imageView.frame.size.width
let height:CGFloat = imageView.frame.size.height
```

**getting size from UIImage (doesn't have coordinates):**

```
let width:CGFloat = image.size.width
let height:CGFloat = image.size.height
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the pixels from image and after getting `CGRect` from image compare with your device width and height.

```
- (CGRect)getRectFromImage:(UIImage*)image
{

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;

    int xMax = 0;
    int yMax = 0;


    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            unsigned char alphaByte = rawData[(y*bytesPerRow)+(x*bytesPerPixel)+3];
            if (alphaByte > 0) {

             if (xPos == 0) {
                xPos = x;
            }

            if (yPos == 0) {
                yPos = y;
            }             
                if (x < xPos) {
                    xPos = x;
                }

                if (y < yPos) {
                    yPos = y;
                }

                if (x > xMax) {
                    xMax = x;
                }

                if (y > yMax) {
                    yMax = y;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"(%i,%i,%i,%i)", xPos, yPos,xMax-xPos,yMax-yPos);


    free(rawData);

    return CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, xMax-xPos, yMax-yPos);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift 3 Xcode 8 .
It works only in `viewDidAppear` function

```
@IBOutlet var myImage: UIImageView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let Height = myImage.frame.height
    let Width = myImage.frame.width
    let xPosition = myImage.frame.minX
    let yPosition = myImage.frame.minY

    print("Height: \(Height), width: \(Width), xPosition: \(xPosition), yPosition: \(yPosition)")

}
```

Comment: i need shape frame not image view

Comment: i have lots of different shape images  and different position in particular image like this image